# Move column in printf?

Tags: perl, printf

If I do

```
perl -e 'printf("%2s %-5s %s\n", "a", "b", "c")'
```

then I get

```
 a b     c
```

**Question**

How can I move `b` e.g. 4 columns to the right, but still so it is left aligned?

(I don't suppose the correct way would be to manually insert white spaces)

Comment: Yes, if you want a fixed-space gap between the columns just insert whitespace as part of the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Why not?

```
perl -e 'printf("%2s     %-5s %s\n", "a", "b", "c")'
```

Comment: A dynamic solution would be to create a string to insert, such as `my $x = " " x 4; printf "%2s %s%-5s ...", "a", $x, "b"`

Comment: @TLP, `perl -e 'printf("%2s %*s%-5s %s\n", "a", 4, "b", "c")'`

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember this... claims to be missing an argument, though. Can't seem to spot this in the documentation.